# cppcheck throws syntaxError with #ifdef

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I have a file that can be summarized as shown below.

```
namespace MyNamespace {

#if defined(SOME_UNSET_CONDITION)

TEST_CASE("STR1", "[STR2]") {
}

TEST_CASE("STR3", "[STR4]") {
}

#endif

}
```

When calling Cppcheck v2.8 on the file, the following is the output:

```
$ cppcheck --std=c++14 -v tmp.cpp
Checking tmp.cpp ...
Defines:
Undefines:
Includes:
Platform:Native
Checking tmp.cpp: SOME_UNSET_CONDITION...
tmp.cpp:8:1: error: syntax error [syntaxError]
TEST_CASE("STR3", "[STR4]") {
^
```

The `SOME_UNSENT_CONDITION` directive is not currently enabled in this project, though I'm not sure why `cppcheck` would be complaining either way. Can anyone give me some insight here?

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone give me some insight here?

From https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf :

> Automatic configuration of preprocessor defines
>
> Cppcheck automatically test different combinations of preprocessor defines to achieve as
> high coverage in the analysis as possible.

By that it is meant that cppcheck checks *every possible combination of all possible defines* in your project.

If you intent to disable checking a specific combination, `-USOME_UNSET_CONDITION` for cppcheck.

Comment: thanks for your response. So, is this error trying to indicate that it's attempting to check `TEST_CASE`, but that it doesn't know where to find it? `syntaxError` seems like the wrong error to throw if that's true.

Comment: `TEST_CASE("STR3", "[STR4]") {` is invalid function declaration, it's a syntax error, I do not understand. `is this error trying to indicate that it's attempting to check TEST_CASE` Yes. `that it doesn't know where to find it?` Yes.